# Is this trigonometric identity true? $\frac{\cos{x} - \cos{y}}{x-y}= \cos{x}$

Tags: trigonometry

I saw this example in a book:

$$\frac{\cos{x} - \cos{\frac{\pi}{2}}}{x - \frac{\pi}{2}} = \cos{x}$$

> Is this a general rule?
>
> $$\frac{\cos{x} - \cos{y}}{x-y}= \cos{x}$$

Comment: What does your first identity say when $x = 0$? You should check the book where you found that example.

Comment: Where did you see that?

Answer (score 1):

No, as a counter example, let $x=\pi$ and $y=\pi/2$.

$$\frac{\cos(\pi)-\cos(\pi/2)}{\pi-\pi/2}=\frac{-1-0}{\pi/2}=-2/\pi$$

whereas $\cos(\pi)=-1$

so in this case

$$\frac{\cos(x)-\cos(y)}{x-y}\neq \cos(x)$$

Also it is possible that in your book there might be other constraints because obviously you cannot have $x=y$. Maybe under certain conditions that statement follows, but in general that is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Of course not. With $y=0$ it says $\cos x - 1 = x \cos x$.